# Injecting Angular 2 Router not working

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular-ui-router

I posted a question earlier about DI and I have since found the same problem here. I dont know if its something Im doing or my dev setup?

Im trying to inject Router into a component. My containing module looks like this

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { LoginComponent }  from './login.component';

import { User } from '../user/user';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, Router ],
  declarations: [ LoginComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ LoginComponent ]
})

export class LoginModule { }
```

And this is my component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { User } from '../user/user';

@Component({
  templateUrl: './login.template.html'
})

export class LoginComponent { 
    user = new User( "", "" );
    submitted:boolean = false;
    inProgress:boolean = false;

    constructor ( private router : Router ) {

    } 

}
```

When I run the application I get the following error

```
Can't resolve all parameters for LoginComponent
```

My build process is as follows:

run inline-angular-compiler (To embed templateUrl's in actual js files)
run tsc (to convert from ts to js)

Ive heard that running a typescript converter can lead to DI problems but what is the alternative?

Edit:

My Router setup

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';

import { UserRoutes } from './user/user.routing';
import { DashboardRoutes } from './dashboard/dashboard.routing';
import { LoginRoutes } from './login/login.routing';

const routes: Routes = [
    ...UserRoutes,
    ...DashboardRoutes,
    ...LoginRoutes,
    //this needs to redirect to a homepage
    {path:'', component: DashboardComponent}
];

export const appRoutingProviders: any[] = [

];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot( routes );
```

Comment: where is your routing configuration? you should import `RouterModule` not `Router` into your imports.

Comment: Im attempting to use router.navigate. So I dont think importing RouterModule would work?? I have a standard router setup, but ill add it above for reference @MadhuRanjan

Comment: Adding the `Router` to `imports` in `NgModule` is definitely wrong. Don't mix up TypeScript imports with module imports. You need to import `routing` (`RouterModule.forRoot(routes)`) in the `AppModule`. I don't see this code in your question. I also think you should import `RouterModule` in `NgModule` of `LoginModule`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i did some reading and it turns out that some typescript compilers dont treat the Angular DI the same way the tsc that Angular recommends. I had previously been using my own build process that used a different type script compiler.

The solution was to revert my build process back to using the one recommended by angular. A pretty strange problem and a hard one to diagnose.

Thanks for the help everyone.